# One C++ application can not open 2 SQLite databases in one thread on linux?

Tags: c++, database, linux, sqlite

I actually seem to have problem with this (only on linux, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019485/invisiable-sigsegv-on-linux-that-does-not-happen-on-windows) with stacktrace like

```
==11682==    at 0x0: ??? // Here goes the error=(
==11682==    by 0x4D49BE: sqlite3_free (sqlite3.c:18155)
==11682==    by 0x102242D5: sqlite3OsInit (sqlite3.c:14162)
==11682==    by 0x1029EB28: sqlite3_initialize (sqlite3.c:107299)
==11682==    by 0x102A159F: openDatabase (sqlite3.c:108909)
==11682==    by 0x102A1B29: sqlite3_open (sqlite3.c:109156)
==11682==    by 0x1021CAB0: sqlite3pp::database::connect(char const*) (sqlite3pp.cpp:89)
==11682==    by 0x1021C6E3: sqlite3pp::database::database(char const*) (sqlite3pp.cpp:74)
```

) so I have one thread that calls 2 similar functions of 2 difrent classes using [sqlitecpp](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite3pp/)

Functions look like this

```
void user_control::start_work_with_db( std::string db_name )
{
    if (!is_db_set) // TODO: find out how to detach from one db and connect to another.
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<sqlite3pp::database> db_( new sqlite3pp::database(db_name.c_str())); //I could not get `db = new sqlite3pp::database(DB_name.c_str());` to compile
        db = db_;
        *lu << "Connected to "<< db_name << " database and created a table with SQLite return code: " << db->execute(command_create_users_table.c_str()) << log_util::endl;
    }
}
```

and

```
void users_files_service::create_files_table( std::string db_name )
{
    if(!is_db_set) // TODO: find out how to detach from one db and connect to another.
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<sqlite3pp::database> db_( new sqlite3pp::database(db_name.c_str())); //I could not get `db = new sqlite3pp::database(DB_name.c_str());` to compile
        db = db_;
        *lu << "Connected to "<< db_name << " database and created a table with SQLite return code: " << db->execute(command_create_files_table.c_str()) << log_util::endl;
        is_db_set = true;
    }
}
```

and command_create_files_table looks like

```
command_create_files_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (encoded_url varchar(300) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, file_name varchar(150) NOT NULL, user_name varchar(65) NOT NULL, is_public BOOLEAN NOT NULL, modified DATETIME NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )";
```

and

```
command_create_users_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (email varchar(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL primary key, pass varchar(100))";
```

and `db` is private member of each of classes.

I wonder - do I have an error somewhere in presented code or SQLite does not suppor operating on 2 DB files from one thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) library most certainly supports opening multiple DB files from the same thread - I have repeatedly done so on both Linux and Windows. It is both possible and useful, as long as you do not twist yourself up by opening *the same* DB file twice and trying to interleave transactions, in which case your thread may just deadlock - not crash.

This line is indicative of stack corruption:

```
==11682==    at 0x0: ???
```

You might want to use [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) to further track this issue down. There are a few tips for using Valgrind in [this past answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297633/enabling-no-memory-management-in-gcc/4297799#4297799).